# Does "octopus" get a circumflex?

Tags: orthography

I just learned (from Pé de Leão [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6157/118)) that in Neo-Latin orthography, Latin words that come from Greek names that end in -οῦς get a circumflex in imitation of the Greek circumflex, e.g. Trapezûs, Hierichûs. See, for example, p. 16 of [this summary](http://www.flf.vu.lt/dokumentai/mokslas/Disertacijos/Strockis_Dissertation_Summary.pdf) of Mindaugas Strockis's doctoral dissertation, *Accent Notation in the Classical Languages and its Influence on Lithuanian Accent Notation.*

So, does *octopus* get a circumflex?

Comment: Apparently the second-declension *polypus, polypi* was the usual substantive used for "octopus" in Classical Latin; I'm still not sure when or how *octopus* was used in Latin ... (fdb made some comments on related posts like https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/371/examples-of-species-whose-latin-and-scientific-names-are-different/871#comment10597_871, https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5080/is-there-an-exclusive-word-for-octopus-in-ancient-greek, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/what-is-the-correct-plural-of-octopus/138236#comment967371_138236)

Comment: Just a note to anyone answering this question: According to Strockis' dissertation, *Hierichûs* (Jericho) should correspond to Ἱεριχοῦς, and that is, in fact, the case according to the spelling of some, such as the geographer [Stephanus Byzantius](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=oJg-AAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see pg. 807). However, someone searching for Jericho in Greek will likely find the more common spelling Ἰεριχώ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because in ancient Greek, ὀκτώπους (gen. ὀκτώποδος) does not end in -οῦς, but in -ους. So in Latin it would become octōpūs (gen. octōpodis) with long ū, without circumflex.